# How to keep two or three command lines in memory? (not in history)

Tags: zsh

I'd like to continue using [zsh-history-substring-search](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search) with the up key, which prints the previous command line (if available) and cycles through fuzzy history matches upon successive presses.

However, I wounder how I could retain previous command lines which are ignored with 
`$HISTORY_IGNORE` a bit longer, so that I can always access, say, the previous three lines, without writing them to a file.

Comment: Just a tip: Do you know about `Ctrl + U` (stash) and `Ctrl + Y` (yank)?

Comment: Also, try `!-1`, `!-2` etc. for reverse lookup.

Comment: hi, how does stashing with `Ctrl + U` work? Is this a zsh feature? I can't find it in the man pages. Reverse lookup takes me to history entries though. (I use vi mode)

Comment: I'm not really sure where it comes from, bash also supports it. Enter a command but do not submit it, leave the cursor on the last position, hit `Ctrl + U` to store. Later, on an empty prompt, use `Ctrl + Y` to restore.

Comment: @Panki, zsh has proper stashing with Alt+Q, that Ctrl+U / Ctrl+Y is just cut-and-paste (kill-and-yank)